# Export polygon attribute table CSV file failed - QGIS 2.14

Tags: attribute-table, convert, csv, qgis-2.14

When I convert a polygon attribute table into CSV file I get columns with gibberish font. I don't care about the coordinates of the features. i just need the attribute table readable.

I tried to use MMQGIS plugin and also try to save as CSV file- both ways failed and I got a gibberish font (the original font is right to left hand writing)

[image]

How can I convert it well?

Comment: What was the encoding when you saved to CSV?

Comment: Looks like wrong encoding on export. Tried to reproduce export (`Save as... --> .csv`), works fine for me (2.14.11) even with diacritic.